# How can I extract the formal java method arguments in python and add them to a list of strings?

Tags: java, python

I have a java method, I need the arguments passed to this method from the method declaration. The code below gives should extract the method declaration but outputs `None`

I would like the extracted arguments to be added into a list of strings.

```
import re
f = open("source_code.txt", "r")
source_code = f.read()

match = re.match("(public|protected|private|static|\s) +[\w\<\>\[\]]+\s+(\w+) *\([^\)]*\) *(\{?|[^;])", source_code)

print(match)
```

I would like something like this:

INPUT:

```
/**
    * Adds a subset of the edges of the specified source graph to the specified destination graph.
    * The behavior of this operation is undefined if either of the graphs is modified while the
    * operation is in progress. {@link #addEdgeWithVertices} is used for the transfer, so source
    * vertexes will be added automatically to the target graph.
    *
    * @param destination the graph to which edges are to be added
    * @param source the graph used as a source for edges to add
    * @param edges the edges to be added
    * @param <V> the graph vertex type
    * @param <E> the graph edge type
    *
    * @return <tt>true</tt> if this graph changed as a result of the call
    */
public static <V, E> boolean addAllEdges(Graph<? super V, ? super E> destination, Graph<V, E> source, Collection<? extends E> edges)
   {
       boolean modified = false;
       for (E e : edges) {
           V s = source.getEdgeSource(e);
           V t = source.getEdgeTarget(e);
           destination.addVertex(s);
           destination.addVertex(t);
           modified |= destination.addEdge(s, t, e);
       }
       return modified;


   }
```

This extracts `destination`, `source`, `edge` from the method declaration: `public static <V, E> boolean addAllEdges(Graph<? super V, ? super E> destination, Graph<V, E> source, Collection<? extends E> edges)`

OUTPUT:

```
extracted_arguments = ['destination', 'source', 'edge']
```

Comment: I added in more to my question, hope that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moreover you have to use a [parser](https://github.com/c2nes/javalang) for this

Here this finds the method args and split

```
import re
match = re.search("(public|protected|private|static) .*\((.*)\)", source_code)
args=[i.split()[-1] for i in re.sub('<.*?>','',match[2]).split(',')]
print(args)
```